# How to load a data to collapse bar on a click event of a row in a grid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, onclick

I have created the **click event on a row of grid**. I can get the **row index** of the selecting row. But according to my code it **refreshes the page** when click on a row. Here what i expect to do is load the data in the database according to the selected row to collapse bar. Also as soon as i click on the row i table colour changes and make the whole grid white. I want to avoid it too and keep the same colors but change color when the mouse pointer on a row. Everything in here works fine upto now.

**As a summery these are the things i want to perform,**
1) Load relevant data from the database according to the selected value from the grid.
2) Avoid change of colors on a row click.
3) Change colour of a row when the mouse pointer is on that particular row.

Here is my code

```html
<div id="div1" style="width: 100%; height: 50px; float: left; margin-top: 15px">
        <asp:GridView ID="grdSum" runat="server" Style="margin-top: 10px; text-align:center;" 
            onrowdatabound="grdSum_RowDataBound" 
            onrowcreated="grdSum_RowCreated" 
            onselectedindexchanged="grdSum_SelectedIndexChanged" CellPadding="4" 
            ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDummy" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
</div>

<div id="collapse" style="width: 100%; height: auto; margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 10px;float: left">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group
                                1</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Data should be loaded in here</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group
                                2</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Data should be loaded in here</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Collapsible Group
                                3</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Data should be loaded in here</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
protected void grdSum_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
          e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] =   Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(grdSum, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);           
          e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select this row.";
     }
}

protected void grdSum_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     foreach (GridViewRow row in grdSum.Rows)
     {
         if (row.RowIndex == grdSum.SelectedIndex)
         {
              row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#A1DCF2");
              row.ToolTip = string.Empty;
         }
         else
         {
              row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");
              row.ToolTip = "Click to select this row.";
              this.grdSum.RowStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
              this.grdSum.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor =Color.White;
         }
     }
}
```

Code to load data to the grid

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt=db.loadAppealDetails(ddlValue);
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
     grdSum.DataSource = dt;
     grdSum.DataBind();
}
```

Preceding code is in a method and that method is called inside a SelectedIndexChanged method of dropdownlist

Comment: Did you miss something to define in `gridview`?

Comment: because i cannot see anything in `gridview`, and for your 2nd task you need to remove `SelectedRowStyle` property from `gridview`

Comment: @Kinjal, No i havent missed anything in the gridview. I hope you are asking about the columns. They are to be loaded from the database from a query including header names.

Comment: Can you  show your `gridview` `binding` `code`?

Comment: Is it necessary? Because there is no error with binding data to the grid?

Comment: ok No Problem just tell me wich methode you are using to `bind` `gridView`

Comment: I have edited the question and added method fro the data binding. Take look